# How to get the list of filter names in CIFilter class?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am using the following code for exposure adjustment and its working. I need the filter names for sharpen, denoise, highlighs, color temperature, shadows, blur, etc.

```
[CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIExposureAdjust"
                      keysAndValues: @"inputImage", [_imageView image], nil];
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was writing to your earlier post link to all filters. I will repeat: [link to all filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/).

And for example You need Blur effect. Blur is category and have 7 filters:

- CIBoxBlur
- CIDiscBlur
- CIGaussianBlur
- CIMedianFilter
- CIMotionBlur
- CINoiseReduction
- CIZoomBlur.

And etc..

Answer (score 22):

I found the list of names in CIFilter class, core image filters. here is the link [names in CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346) and the list of the filters.

**Filters**

**CICategoryBlur**
CIBoxBlur
CIDiscBlur
CIGaussianBlur
CIMaskedVariableBlur
CIMedianFilter
CIMotionBlur
CINoiseReduction

**CICategoryColorAdjustment**
CIColorClamp
CIColorControls
CIColorMatrix
CIColorPolynomial
CIExposureAdjust
CIGammaAdjust
CIHueAdjust
CILinearToSRGBToneCurve
CISRGBToneCurveToLinear
CITemperatureAndTint
CIToneCurve
CIVibrance
CIWhitePointAdjust

**CICategoryColorEffect**
CIColorCrossPolynomial
CIColorCube
CIColorCubeWithColorSpace
CIColorInvert
CIColorMap
CIColorMonochrome
CIColorPosterize
CIFalseColor
CIMaskToAlpha
CIMaximumComponent
CIMinimumComponent
CIPhotoEffectChrome
CIPhotoEffectFade
CIPhotoEffectInstant
CIPhotoEffectMono
CIPhotoEffectNoir
CIPhotoEffectProcess
CIPhotoEffectTonal
CIPhotoEffectTransfer
CISepiaTone
CIVignette
CIVignetteEffect

**CICategoryCompositeOperation**
CIAdditionCompositing
CIColorBlendMode
CIColorBurnBlendMode
CIColorDodgeBlendMode
CIDarkenBlendMode
CIDifferenceBlendMode
CIDivideBlendMode
CIExclusionBlendMode
CIHardLightBlendMode
CIHueBlendMode
CILightenBlendMode
CILinearBurnBlendMode
CILinearDodgeBlendMode
CILuminosityBlendMode
CIMaximumCompositing
CIMinimumCompositing
CIMultiplyBlendMode
CIMultiplyCompositing
CIOverlayBlendMode
CIPinLightBlendMode
CISaturationBlendMode
CIScreenBlendMode
CISoftLightBlendMode
CISourceAtopCompositing
CISourceInCompositing
CISourceOutCompositing
CISourceOverCompositing
CISubtractBlendMode

**CICategoryDistortionEffect**
CIBumpDistortion
CIBumpDistortionLinear
CICircleSplashDistortion
CICircularWrap
CIDroste
CIDisplacementDistortion
CIGlassDistortion
CIGlassLozenge
CIHoleDistortion
CILightTunnel
CIPinchDistortion
CIStretchCrop
CITorusLensDistortion
CITwirlDistortion
CIVortexDistortion

**CICategoryGenerator**
CIAztecCodeGenerator
CICheckerboardGenerator
CICode128BarcodeGenerator
CIConstantColorGenerator
CILenticularHaloGenerator
CIPDF417BarcodeGenerator
CIQRCodeGenerator
CIRandomGenerator
CIStarShineGenerator
CIStripesGenerator
CISunbeamsGenerator

**CICategoryGeometryAdjustment**
CIAffineTransform
CICrop
CILanczosScaleTransform
CIPerspectiveCorrection
CIPerspectiveTransform
CIPerspectiveTransformWithExtent
CIStraightenFilter

**CICategoryGradient**
CIGaussianGradient
CILinearGradient
CIRadialGradient
CISmoothLinearGradient

**CICategoryHalftoneEffect**
CICircularScreen
CICMYKHalftone
CIDotScreen
CIHatchedScreen
CILineScreen

**CICategoryReduction**
CIAreaAverage
CIAreaHistogram
CIRowAverage
CIColumnAverage
CIHistogramDisplayFilter
CIAreaMaximum
CIAreaMinimum
CIAreaMaximumAlpha
CIAreaMinimumAlpha

**CICategorySharpen**
CISharpenLuminance
CIUnsharpMask

**CICategoryStylize**
CIBlendWithAlphaMask
CIBlendWithMask
CIBloom
CIComicEffect
CIConvolution3X3
CIConvolution5X5
CIConvolution7X7
CIConvolution9Horizontal
CIConvolution9Vertical
CICrystallize
CIDepthOfField
CIEdges
CIEdgeWork
CIGloom
CIHeightFieldFromMask
CIHexagonalPixellate
CIHighlightShadowAdjust
CILineOverlay
CIPixellate
CIPointillize
CIShadedMaterial
CISpotColor
CISpotLight

**CICategoryTileEffect**
CIAffineClamp
CIAffineTile
CIEightfoldReflectedTile
CIFourfoldReflectedTile
CIFourfoldRotatedTile
CIFourfoldTranslatedTile
CIGlideReflectedTile
CIKaleidoscope
CIOpTile
CIParallelogramTile
CIPerspectiveTile
CISixfoldReflectedTile
CISixfoldRotatedTile
CITriangleKaleidoscope
CITriangleTile
CITwelvefoldReflectedTile

**CICategoryTransition**
CIAccordionFoldTransition
CIBarsSwipeTransition
CICopyMachineTransition
CIDisintegrateWithMaskTransition
CIDissolveTransition
CIFlashTransition
CIModTransition
CIPageCurlTransition
CIPageCurlWithShadowTransition
CIRippleTransition
CISwipeTransition

Comment: This is the real useful answer.

Comment: Note that some of these are only for MacOSX and not available for iOS.

Answer (score 20):

All you need to do is ask `CIFilter` for the filter names. You can then ask each filter for its `attributes`, which returns a dictionary that describes each input and output parameter that the filter accepts.

```
NSArray* filters = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:nil];
for (NSString* filterName in filters)
{
    NSLog(@"Filter: %@", filterName);
    NSLog(@"Parameters: %@", [[CIFilter filterWithName:filterName] attributes]);
}
```

For example, this is the output of the above code for the `CIZoomBlur` filter:

```
Filter: CIZoomBlur
Parameters: {
    CIAttributeDescription = "Simulates the effect of zooming the camera while capturing the image.";
    CIAttributeFilterCategories =     (
        CICategoryBlur,
        CICategoryVideo,
        CICategoryStillImage,
        CICategoryBuiltIn
    );
    CIAttributeFilterDisplayName = "Zoom Blur";
    CIAttributeFilterName = CIZoomBlur;
    CIAttributeReferenceDocumentation = "http://developer.apple.com/cgi-bin/apple_ref.cgi?apple_ref=//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIZoomBlur";
    inputAmount =     {
        CIAttributeClass = NSNumber;
        CIAttributeDefault = 20;
        CIAttributeDescription = "The zoom-in amount. Larger values result in more zooming in.";
        CIAttributeDisplayName = Amount;
        CIAttributeIdentity = 0;
        CIAttributeMin = 0;
        CIAttributeSliderMax = 200;
        CIAttributeSliderMin = 0;
        CIAttributeType = CIAttributeTypeDistance;
        CIUIParameterSet = CIUISetBasic;
    };
    inputCenter =     {
        CIAttributeClass = CIVector;
        CIAttributeDefault = "[150 150]";
        CIAttributeDescription = "The x and y position to use as the center of the effect.";
        CIAttributeDisplayName = Center;
        CIAttributeType = CIAttributeTypePosition;
        CIUIParameterSet = CIUISetBasic;
    };
    inputImage =     {
        CIAttributeClass = CIImage;
        CIAttributeDescription = "The image to use as an input image. For filters that also use a background image, this is the foreground image.";
        CIAttributeDisplayName = Image;
        CIUIParameterSet = CIUISetBasic;
    };
    outputImage =     {
        CIAttributeClass = CIImage;
    };
}
```

Most of the time, though, you'll probably just use [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try following method of CIFilter class

```
+ (NSArray *)filterNamesInCategory:(NSString *)category
```

Comment: `[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:nil]` gets you all filters.

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift (4.2, at the time of writing this), you can use this code to get all filter names**:

For filters in a **specified category**:

```
CIFilter.filterNames(inCategory: "Name_of_the_category")
```

For filters in **specified categories**:

```
CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: ["Name_of_the_category_1", "Name_of_the_category_2"])
```

For filters in **all categories**, just pass nil either in inCategory or inCategories:

```
CIFilter.filterNames(inCategory: nil)
```

or

```
CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: nil)
```

All the functions above returns an `Array` of the filter names in `String` values:

`[
    "CIAccordionFoldTransition",
    "CIAdditionCompositing",
    "CIAffineClamp",
    "CIAffineTile",
    "CIAffineTransform",
    "CIAreaAverage",
    "CIAreaHistogram"...
]`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Distortion: %@", [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryDistortionEffect]);
NSLog(@"Blurs: %@", [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBlur]);
NSLog(@"Color effects: %@", [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryColorEffect]);
NSLog(@"Color adjustment: %@", [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryColorAdjustment]);
NSLog(@"Built-in effects: %@", [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn]);
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 14, Swift 5

Must confess not easy to read, but an answer that is comparable to the first one on Objective C.

```
for filtername in filters {
  print("filter \(filtername)")
  print("attributes \(CIFilter.init(name: filtername)?.attributes.keys.description)")
}
```

Produces this ...

```
filter CIAccordionFoldTransition
attributes Optional("[\"inputImage\", \"CIAttributeFilterDisplayName\",     \"inputTargetImage\", \"CIAttributeFilterAvailable_iOS\", \"CIAttributeFilterAvailable_Mac\", \"inputNumberOfFolds\", \"inputFoldShadowAmount\", \"inputBottomHeight\", \"CIAttributeReferenceDocumentation\", \"inputTime\", \"CIAttributeFilterCategories\", \"CIAttributeFilterName\"]")
filter CIAdditionCompositing
attributes Optional("[\"CIAttributeFilterCategories\", \"CIAttributeFilterName\", \"CIAttributeFilterDisplayName\", \"inputImage\", \"CIAttributeReferenceDocumentation\", \"CIAttributeFilterAvailable_iOS\", \"CIAttributeFilterAvailable_Mac\", \"inputBackgroundImage\"]")
```

So the info is there in these long strings, you just need to pick it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Noah Gilmore has a very handy filter tool to demo and document almost all cifilters & filter parms..
See on the app store 'CIFilter.io'. He also has the same on the web site https://cifilter.io

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 14, Swift 5**

Here you can find also array of the CIFilter functions which is supported with the protocol.

```
                      CIFilter.hueSaturationValueGradient(),
                      CIFilter.linearGradient(),
                      CIFilter.radialGradient(),
                      CIFilter.smoothLinearGradient(),
                      CIFilter.sharpenLuminance(),
                      CIFilter.unsharpMask(),
                      CIFilter.dotScreen(),
                      CIFilter.hatchedScreen(),
                      CIFilter.lineScreen(),
                      CIFilter.bicubicScaleTransform(),
                      CIFilter.edgePreserveUpsample(),
                      CIFilter.keystoneCorrectionCombined(),
                      CIFilter.keystoneCorrectionHorizontal(),
                      CIFilter.keystoneCorrectionVertical(),
                      CIFilter.lanczosScaleTransform(),
                      CIFilter.perspectiveCorrection(),
                      CIFilter.perspectiveRotate(),
                      CIFilter.perspectiveTransform(),
                      CIFilter.perspectiveTransformWithExtent(),
                      CIFilter.straighten(),
                      CIFilter.accordionFoldTransition(),
                      CIFilter.barsSwipeTransition(),
                      CIFilter.copyMachineTransition(),
                      CIFilter.disintegrateWithMaskTransition(),
                      CIFilter.dissolveTransition(),
                      CIFilter.flashTransition(),
                      CIFilter.modTransition(),
                      CIFilter.pageCurlTransition(),
                      CIFilter.pageCurlWithShadowTransition(),
                      CIFilter.rippleTransition(),
                      CIFilter.swipeTransition(),
                      CIFilter.additionCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.colorBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.colorBurnBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.colorDodgeBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.darkenBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.differenceBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.divideBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.exclusionBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.hardLightBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.hueBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.lightenBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.linearBurnBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.linearDodgeBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.luminosityBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.maximumCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.minimumCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.multiplyBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.multiplyCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.overlayBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.pinLightBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.saturationBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.screenBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.softLightBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.sourceAtopCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.sourceInCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.sourceOutCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.sourceOverCompositing(),
                      CIFilter.subtractBlendMode(),
                      CIFilter.colorAbsoluteDifference(),
                      CIFilter.colorClamp(),
                      CIFilter.colorControls(),
                      CIFilter.colorMatrix(),
                      CIFilter.colorPolynomial(),
                      CIFilter.colorThreshold(),
                      CIFilter.colorThresholdOtsu(),
                      CIFilter.depthToDisparity(),
                      CIFilter.disparityToDepth(),
                      CIFilter.exposureAdjust(),
                      CIFilter.gammaAdjust(),
                      CIFilter.hueAdjust(),
                      CIFilter.linearToSRGBToneCurve(),
                      CIFilter.sRGBToneCurveToLinear(),
                      CIFilter.temperatureAndTint(),
                      CIFilter.toneCurve(),
                      CIFilter.vibrance(),
                      CIFilter.whitePointAdjust(),
                      CIFilter.colorCrossPolynomial(),
                      CIFilter.colorCube(),
                      CIFilter.colorCubesMixedWithMask(),
                      CIFilter.colorCubeWithColorSpace(),
                      CIFilter.colorCurves(),
                      CIFilter.colorInvert(),
                      CIFilter.colorMap(),
                      CIFilter.colorMonochrome(),
                      CIFilter.colorPosterize(),
                      CIFilter.dither(),
                      CIFilter.documentEnhancer(),
                      CIFilter.falseColor(),
                      CIFilter.labDeltaE(),
                      CIFilter.maskToAlpha(),
                      CIFilter.maximumComponent(),
                      CIFilter.minimumComponent(),
                      CIFilter.paletteCentroid(),
                      CIFilter.palettize(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectChrome(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectFade(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectInstant(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectMono(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectNoir(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectProcess(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectTonal(),
                      CIFilter.photoEffectTransfer(),
                      CIFilter.sepiaTone(),
                      CIFilter.thermal(),
                      CIFilter.vignette(),
                      CIFilter.vignetteEffect(),
                      CIFilter.xRay(),
                      CIFilter.bumpDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.bumpDistortionLinear(),
                      CIFilter.circleSplashDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.circularWrap(),
                      CIFilter.displacementDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.droste(),
                      CIFilter.glassDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.glassLozenge(),
                      CIFilter.holeDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.lightTunnel(),
                      CIFilter.ninePartStretched(),
                      CIFilter.ninePartTiled(),
                      CIFilter.pinchDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.stretchCrop(),
                      CIFilter.torusLensDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.twirlDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.vortexDistortion(),
                      CIFilter.affineClamp(),
                      CIFilter.affineTile(),
                      CIFilter.eightfoldReflectedTile(),
                      CIFilter.fourfoldReflectedTile(),
                      CIFilter.fourfoldRotatedTile(),
                      CIFilter.fourfoldTranslatedTile(),
                      CIFilter.glideReflectedTile(),
                      CIFilter.kaleidoscope(),
                      CIFilter.opTile(),
                      CIFilter.parallelogramTile(),
                      CIFilter.perspectiveTile(),
                      CIFilter.sixfoldReflectedTile(),
                      CIFilter.sixfoldRotatedTile(),
                      CIFilter.triangleKaleidoscope(),
                      CIFilter.triangleTile(),
                      CIFilter.twelvefoldReflectedTile(),
                      CIFilter.attributedTextImageGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.aztecCodeGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.barcodeGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.checkerboardGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.code128BarcodeGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.lenticularHaloGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.meshGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.pdf417BarcodeGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.randomGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.roundedRectangleGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.starShineGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.stripesGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.sunbeamsGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.textImageGenerator(),
                      CIFilter.blendWithAlphaMask(),
                      CIFilter.blendWithBlueMask(),
                      CIFilter.blendWithMask(),
                      CIFilter.blendWithRedMask(),
                      CIFilter.bloom(),
                      CIFilter.comicEffect(),
                      CIFilter.convolution3X3(),
                      CIFilter.convolution5X5(),
                      CIFilter.convolution7X7(),
                      CIFilter.convolution9Horizontal(),
                      CIFilter.convolution9Vertical(),
                      CIFilter.coreMLModel(),
                      CIFilter.crystallize(),
                      CIFilter.depthOfField(),
                      CIFilter.edges(),
                      CIFilter.edgeWork(),
                      CIFilter.gaborGradients(),
                      CIFilter.gloom(),
                      CIFilter.heightFieldFromMask(),
                      CIFilter.hexagonalPixellate(),
                      CIFilter.highlightShadowAdjust(),
                      CIFilter.lineOverlay(),
                      CIFilter.mix(),
                      CIFilter.pixellate(),
                      CIFilter.pointillize(),
                      CIFilter.saliencyMap(),
                      CIFilter.shadedMaterial(),
                      CIFilter.spotColor(),
                      CIFilter.spotLight(),
                      CIFilter.bokehBlur(),
                      CIFilter.boxBlur(),
                      CIFilter.discBlur(),
                      CIFilter.gaussianBlur(),
                      CIFilter.maskedVariableBlur(),
                      CIFilter.median(),
                      CIFilter.morphologyGradient(),
                      CIFilter.morphologyMaximum(),
                      CIFilter.morphologyMinimum(),
                      CIFilter.morphologyRectangleMaximum(),
                      CIFilter.morphologyRectangleMinimum(),
                      CIFilter.motionBlur(),
                      CIFilter.noiseReduction(),
                      CIFilter.zoomBlur] as [AnyObject]
```