# How to find the CIFIlter categories at runtime?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm using this `[CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:nil]` to get the list of available filters, but how can I get the list of categories ? I could certainly enumerate through the filters list, and read the categories in each filter to build a set, but is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
NSMutableSet  * categories = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSString* filterName in [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:nil])
{
    for (id value in  [[[CIFilter filterWithName:filterName] attributes] 
    valueForKey:@"CIAttributeFilterCategories"]) {
        [categories addObject:value];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 version is here.

```
  import CoreImage

  var results = NSMutableSet()
  let categories = CIFilter.filterNames(inCategory: nil)

  for category in categories {
      let attributes = CIFilter(name: category)?.attributes
      let filterCategories = attributes!["CIAttributeFilterCategories"]
      results.addObjects(from: filterCategories as! [Any])
  }

  print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [from the documentation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Filter_Category_Keys)

> Filter Category Keys
>
> Categories of filters.

```
extern NSString *kCICategoryDistortionEffect;
extern NSString *kCICategoryGeometryAdjustment;
extern NSString *kCICategoryCompositeOperation;
extern NSString *kCICategoryHalftoneEffect;
extern NSString *kCICategoryColorAdjustment;
extern NSString *kCICategoryColorEffect;
extern NSString *kCICategoryTransition;
extern NSString *kCICategoryTileEffect;
extern NSString *kCICategoryGenerator;
extern NSString *kCICategoryReduction;
extern NSString *kCICategoryGradient;
extern NSString *kCICategoryStylize;
extern NSString *kCICategorySharpen;
extern NSString *kCICategoryBlur;
extern NSString *kCICategoryVideo;
extern NSString *kCICategoryStillImage;
extern NSString *kCICategoryInterlaced;
extern NSString *kCICategoryNonSquarePixels;
extern NSString *kCICategoryHighDynamicRange ;
extern NSString *kCICategoryBuiltIn;
```

As for getting them in runtime, I don't see any other option, other than enumerating them.
[Here is the answer to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040548/312312)

Comment: @Antoine I have edited my answer, and the only solution I know and see is enumeration. But if you have them in compile them, you certainly can create an array of them and use them in runtime as well...

Comment: I want my code to be platform independant, at least as much as possible. I don't necessarily have them at compile time.